# Why is it so hard to use an internal relay that has no Guard flag as Guard Relay?

Tags: client, guard, guard-node, server

I've set up a tor relay that has no Guard flag, but I want to use it as a Guard relay when I use Tor from outside. But sometimes it works and sometimes not. Why is this so hard and what can I do to use my relay at any time when it's up?

In my client, I added the followind line to the torrc:

```
 EntryNodes $fingerprint_of_my_relay
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: You may have to also add "StrictNodes 1"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn't fix it. My client doesn't use any Tor nodes it wants to use. The two possibilities are:
1) connecting to my Tor relay
2) don't open any circuits because Tor can't find my relay although it's online. What's wrong with it?

Comment: How are you checking that your relay is part of the network?